# How to align divs along a horizontal line across the top and bottom of a container

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having trouble getting quotes (within divs) to line up properly.

This site is here
http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/.

What I need to do is line up the divs (with a class or id of hero) across a horizontal line along the top and the bottom of the picture. For some reason they dont seem to be sitting evenly.

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Would you please clarify? It's not clear what elements you want on top of the picture versus what you'd like on the bottom.

Comment: hi wahwahwah, thanks for your response.

http://postimg.org/image/5xuy8ht19/ 

This is an img that shows the horizontal line at the top and bottom of the image.  The quotes at the top should be up against the underside of the line and the quotes at the bottom should be sitting on top of the line.

Does this make sense now? And thanks for any help you can offer :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the issue you are having is the quotes in the right hand side is a little lower than the other two DIVs.

One of the issues I saw was that there is an empty `<p>` in your right div. If you remove it, the text should line up with the rest of the DIVs. Remove this from your html: `<p><!-- Right div hero section --></p>`

Also, your .entry class has huge amount of padding in it,remove that and it should bring everything down closer.

I'd also recommend removing the other `<p>` tags and using margins for better control off the elements.

**Here is my update to your html.** This work from from browser.

Updated Style.CSS

```
.entry {
  border-bottom-color:#F1F1F1;
  border-bottom-style:solid;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
  padding:50px 50px 45px 0;
```

becomes....

```
.entry {
  border-bottom-color:#F1F1F1;
  border-bottom-style:solid;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
  padding:0 50px 45px 0;
```

**Updated html**

```
<div id="herobox">

    <div id="left-hero">
                    <img src="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/newdoor.jpg" width="265px" height="426px" alt="Robinson Hambro Door">
                </div>

    <div id="centre-hero">
    <h1>
    <p class="pcentre">Robinson Hambro specialises in Board Search and Chairman Advisory. The Firm advises companies with a global outlook drawing on the experience of a multilingual and multidisciplinary team.</p>
    </h1>
    <div class="subcentrehero">
    <p class="p03">Robinson Hambro Chairman Advisory Service is priceless.Լ/p>
    <p class="p04">- Carles Casajuana, former Spanish Ambassador to the UK</p>
    </div>
    <div class="subcentrehero">
    <p class="p03">Robinson Hambro advice was invaluable and I could not recommend them more highly!</p>
    <p class="p04">- Global COO of a $45bn firm</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right-hero">
    <p class="p01">The process was carried out to a high standard, in a timely way, and I can therefore wholeheartedly recommend this service.</p>
    <p class="p02">- Dr Andrew McCulloch, CEO, MHF</p>
    <p class="p01">Karina knows everyone</p>
    <p class="p02">Fiona Woolf, former Lord Mayor of the City of London</p>
    <p class="p01">We would have no hesitation in highly recommending Robinson Hambro for an assignment in any sector.</p>
    <p class="p02">- Robin Walker, Deputy Chairman, Berry Gardens</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                        </article> <!-- end .entry -->
                </div> <!-- end #main_content -->
    </div> <!-- end #content_area -->

                </div> <!-- end .container -->
            </div> <!-- end #main-area -->
        </div> <!-- end #page-wrap -->

        <footer id="main-footer">
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div id="footer-top-shadow"></div>

                                <div id="footer-widgets" class="clearfix">
                        <div class="footer-widget footer-col1"><div id="text-4" class="f_widget widget_text"><h4 class="widgettitle">INSIDER VIEW</h4>          <div class="textwidget">Visit <a href="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/category/all/">Karina's Column</a> for insights on the world of finance by Robinson Hambro's Karina Robinson
    </div>
            </div></div> <!-- end . footer-widget --><div class="footer-widget footer-col2"><div id="text-5" class="f_widget widget_text"><h4 class="widgettitle">What We Do</h4>           <div class="textwidget"><a href="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/guiding-principles/">Guiding Principles</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/chairman-advisory/">Chairman Counsel</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/board-search/">Board Search</a></div>
            </div></div> <!-- end . footer-widget --><div class="footer-widget footer-col3"><div id="text-6" class="f_widget widget_text"><h4 class="widgettitle">Get in touch</h4>         <div class="textwidget">t: +44 (0) 20 3405 2355
    <br/> 
    m: +44 (0) 7980 510 975
    <br/>
    <a href="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/contact-us/">e: info@robinsonhambro.com</a>
    </div>
            </div></div> <!-- end . footer-widget --><div class="footer-widget footer-col4 last"><div id="text-3" class="f_widget widget_text"><h4 class="widgettitle">LINKS</h4>           <div class="textwidget"><a href="http://www.citywomen.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img src="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/women.gif"></a> 

    <a href="http://insideglobalbanking.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bankers.gif"></a> 

    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCre_nrMpCa86oIaGgW4TTfA" target="_blank"><img src="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/youtube.png"></a> 

    <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/110294568454146566422/about" target="blank"><img src="http://79.170.44.107/robinsonhambro.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/googleplus.png"></a> </div>
            </div></div> <!-- end . footer-widget -->               </div> <!-- end #footer-widgets -->

                <p id="copyright">Designed by  <a href="http://www.elegantthemes.com" title="Premium WordPress Themes">Elegant Themes</a> | Powered by  <a href="http://www.wordpress.org">WordPress</a></p>
            </div> <!-- end .container -->
        </footer> <!-- end #main-footer -->
```

Comment: Hi Vin, thanks a mill for that reply. I used inspect element on chrome to delete one of the <p> tags within the id="herobox".  That worked but when I go to custom css it deletes all the paragraphs. 

Is there a way to target that specific (un-named) <p> without targeting all the rest of the <p> tags that all have a class identifier? 

(sorry for the late response, I was working on a college assignment)

Comment: to delete the <p> tag I was using:

          #herobox p {
        display: none;
          }

Comment: I tried your suggestion but for some reason I cant find that empty <p> tag  anywhere except inspect element (chrome). 

Using the editor in home.php the "right div hero section" shows up but the empty <p> tag is not there- all the <p> tags within the <right div..> are the ones that are showing up. 

Sorry if this is something really stupid but Im being totally frustrated by it.

Comment: I updated my post to include the html I updated. You shouldn't have to do anything else to the CSS

Comment: Thats for that. I had just understood your original message and had fixed it. 

I will work on the code suggestions that you mentioned for improving control over the elements. 

Thanks again and sorry to have not understood you properly the first time. 
All the best :-)

Comment: Let me know if it works out for you. And if you like the answer, please feel free to mark it as the correct answer :)